# Reinitialize singleton class after app restart

Tags: android, kotlin, initialization, singleton

An application uses singletons. One of them contains an instance of `Retrofit` client. Another one contains constants.

I can change a server URL in app preferences (in activity), so that after the app restart I expect to reinitialize `Retrofit` client with the new base URL.

After first start all singletons and classes are initialized. Then I change the URL in the activity and restart the application. Now singletons don't initialize and contain old constants. If I forcely stop the app or attach a debugger these singletons restart as expected.

```
object ApiClass {

    private val gsonConverter: GsonConverter = GsonConverter()
    var gson: Gson
        private set
    var retrofit: Retrofit
        private set

    init {
        Timber.i("*** start ApiClass")

        val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
            .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build()

        gson = GsonBuilder().setLenient().create()

        val url = "..." // Get a server URL from preferences.
        Timber.i("*** " + url)

        retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(url)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build()
        ...
    }
}

/////////////

object ApiConst {

    init {
        Timber.i("*** start ApiConst")
    }

    const val SOME_TEXT = "text"
}
```

How to reinitialize singletons without `Force stop` the app?

Comment: I suspect Android might keep some state of your app, the truth is that stateful globals are often problematic, the easy solution is to add a call to reinitialize your 'ApiClass'. A better solution is to stop using singletons and have objects ties to the app lifecylce

Comment: @al3c, thanks! Maybe changing `ApiClass` to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41672427/how-to-make-a-singleton-for-retrofit-2 will help (famous `getInstance()`). I will test.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @al3c I found that it was useless to reinitialize singletons. I tried to change one form of singleton to another (like in [How to make a singleton for retrofit 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41672427/how-to-make-a-singleton-for-retrofit-2)):

```
class ApiClass {

    var gson: Gson private set
    lateinit var retrofit: Retrofit private set
    private val gsonConverter: GsonConverter = GsonConverter()
    private val okHttpClient: OkHttpClient

    init {
        Timber.i("*** start ApiClass")

        okHttpClient = OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
        ...
   }

    companion object {
        private var instance: ApiClass? = null

        fun getInstance(): ApiClass {
            if (instance == null) instance = ApiClass()
            return instance!!
        }
    }
}
```

But calling `ApiClass.getInstance().retrofit` didn't help me to recreate `ApiClass` after restart. Then I tried to change a base URL in `Retrofit` client *before destroying the app* (so that after restart it will have a new URL). After reading [Retrofit - Change BaseUrl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38805689/retrofit-change-baseurl) I wrote:

```
fun setBaseUrl(url: String) {
    retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(url)
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .build()
}
```

Then I was able to call `setBaseUrl` from preferences activity in `onDestroy` to change `Retrofit` client. Also it helped me to continue working with the app with new URL for requests, so that I didn't have to restart the app.